# MySQL: MAX not returning

Tags: mysql

How can I get a list of rows ordered by a maximum column and grouped by an id? I keep getting the correct maximum value, but the other fields are obtained from other rows.

I am using the following:

```
SELECT p.*
            FROM `logs` AS p
            JOIN
            (SELECT person_id,
             MAX(`datetime`) AS datetime
             FROM `logs`
             GROUP BY `person_id`
             ) AS pg
             ON  pg.person_id = p.person_id
             AND pg.`datetime` = p.datetime
             group by person_id
```

Where is my query wrong? Datetime and person id are always correct, but the other fields are not.

Comment: It's wrong because you're selecting fields outside of an aggregate function, and that you're not grouping by. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html

Answer (score 0):

See this: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=54784

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT MIN(datetime) does not always return the minimum datetime
>   value.  Same with MAX.

Temporary workaround:

```
        SELECT p.*
        FROM   `logs` AS p
        JOIN
              (SELECT person_id,
                      MAX(CAST(`datetime` as CHAR(25))) AS `datetime`
               FROM `logs`
               GROUP BY `person_id`
               ) AS pg
                   ON  pg.person_id = p.person_id AND
              pg.`datetime` = p.datetime
         group by person_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below:

```
SELECT logs.* 
  FROM ( SELECT person_id,
             MAX(`datetime`) AS latest
             FROM `logs` 
         GROUP BY person_id) AS dt
INNER
  JOIN logs 
    ON logs.person_id= dt.person_id
   AND logs.datetime= dt.latest
```